# Trying to make comparison between different sheets of data in Google sheets using column pair values

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get to the point where my Google sheet is going to show up like the picture below.

Basically I am trying to find the common column in different table (sheet) and also make sure the type of the columns matches too. The columns are unsorted and won't be of equal length.

[image]

But I am unable to do so using `vlookup` or query which is becoming to complicated. I am attaching the link for the Google sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yk5J_R74yvYTOmOr5LHgMuLD--xT68pOaps8XvhOgy8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
 =IFERROR(MAP(C7:C13,D7:D13, LAMBDA(x,y,IF(XLOOKUP(x,A7:A10,B7:B10)=y,"Match","Mismatch in Type"))),"No Match")
```

This should also work.

```
=INDEX(IFNA(XLOOKUP(--(VLOOKUP(C7:C13,A7:B10,2,0)=D7:D13),{0,1},{"Type Mismatch","Match"}),"No Match"))
```

This will spill results automatically. No need drag down.

[image]

> ***Update:*** Use below formula as dynamic input range from source and target sheet without helper ***QUERY*** function.

```
=MAP(Target!A2:INDEX(Target!A2:A,COUNTA(Target!A2:A)),
LAMBDA(x,IFNA(XLOOKUP(XLOOKUP(x,Source!A2:A,Source!B2:B)=XLOOKUP(x,Target!A2:A,Target!B2:B),
{TRUE,FALSE},{"Match","Type Mismatch"}),"No MAtch")))
```

[image]

Comment: Both the solution are giving me proper results. Thank you so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo in your Source table (you have 'emd_id' where you meant 'emp_id'). If you correct that, you can delete everything in F7 downwards and try the following in F7:

```
=arrayformula(ifna(if(sign(match(C7:C13,A7:A10,0))=ifna(sign(match(C7:C13&D7:D13,A7:A10&B7:B10,0))),"Match","Mismatch in type"),"No match"))
```

We are creating two arrays corresponding to whether the 'column' or 'column' AND 'type' entries match in both Source and Target, then using IF/IFNA to assign the required results based on whether the overall result was TRUE/FALSE/#N/A.

EDIT: To make the formula dynamic (as per the comment):

```
=arrayformula(lambda(source,target,
ifna(if(sign(match(index(target,,1),index(source,,1),0))=ifna(sign(match(index(Target,,1)&index(Target,,2),index(source,,1)&index(source,,2),0))),"Match","Mismatch in type"),"No match"))(
Source!A2:index(Source!B2:B,counta(Source!B2:B)),
Target!A2:index(Target!B2:B,counta(Target!B2:B))))
```

Comment: Ya it was because of the typo it didnt work before. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Just one more question is there a way i can make it dynamic. As the source and the target will keep changing. and i dont want to manually change it. Can len() or offset() function be used in your answer for that dynamism.?@The God of Biscuits

Comment: I've added a dynamic version of the formula to the answer.